# How i can convert a mongo query to laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, mongodb-query, laravel-5.1

I have one collection in mongodb and my document is :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55caf368b649fe6d068b4568"), 
"title" : "lrgwkwjg", 
"comments" : [
    {
        "id" : NumberLong(793644433634148), 
        "name" : "werkwehgbwejhf", 
        "title" : "jrg nejrngjern gjer", 
        "created_at" : {
            "date" : "2015-08-15 11:01:54", 
            "timezone_type" : NumberLong(3), 
            "timezone" : "UTC"
        }, 
        "comment" : "nrjfnwejf wjkenf kjwef", 
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5599009fb649fe72188b4567"), 
        "approve" : false, 
        "url" : "http://takhfif.dev/api/v1/comment/793644433634148"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : NumberLong(966385963890287), 
        "name" : "werkwehgbwejhf", 
        "title" : "jrg nejrngjern gjer", 
        "created_at" : {
            "date" : "2015-08-15 11:09:17", 
            "timezone_type" : NumberLong(3), 
            "timezone" : "UTC"
        }, 
        "comment" : "nrjfnwejf wjkenf kjwef", 
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5599009fb649fe72188b4567"), 
        "approve" : false, 
        "url" : "http://takhfif.dev/api/v1/comment/966385963890287"
    }
],
```

I want to update comments as record id = 966385963890287, and the approve field  must be convert to true - in conclude, i use this query as below:

```
public function approveComment($id,Product $comment)
{
    $comment->update([
    'comments.id'=>$id
    ]
        ,
        [
            '$set'=>[
            'comments.$.approve'=>true
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```

But if i use that query i got an error as below :

```
  MongoWriteConcernException in Collection.php line 42:
  localhost:27017: cannot use the part (comments of comments.id) to traverse the element ({comments: [ { id: 793644433634148, name: "werkwehgbwejhf", title: "jrg nejrngjern gjer", created_at: { date: "2015-08-15 11:01:54", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC" }, comment: "nrjfnwejf wjkenf kjwef", user_id: ObjectId('5599009fb649fe72188b4567'), approve: true, url: "http://takhfif.dev/api/v1/comment/793644433634148" }, { id: 966385963890287, name: "werkwehgbwejhf", title: "jrg nejrngjern gjer", created_at: { date: "2015-08-15 11:09:17", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC" }, comment: "nrjfnwejf wjkenf kjwef", user_id: ObjectId('5599009fb649fe72188b4567'), approve: false, url: "http://takhfif.dev/api/v1/comment/966385963890287" } ]})
```

How can i fix that?

Hint : i use jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package in laravel5.1

Comment: No one can not help me for that question